# How can we apply group_concat using views?

Tags: views

Is there any way we can apply group_concat clause using views and without applying any customization to views ?

Comment: can any one answer this question please ?

Answer (score 0):

After some R & D on the above issue. I found that [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) has that feature which I require. However, there are some minor configuration to be made but this module is quite helpful the result which I was expecting.